# Passing conditional expression into a user definded function with dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to make a function that subsets and mutates data with dplyr commands. My fake data is like this:

```
newTest_rv <- data.frame(is_op=c(rep(0,6),rep(1,4)),
                     has_click=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1),
                     num_pimp=c(3,5,1,2,3,5,2,5,3,5),
                     freq = c(rep(1,5),5,1,2,1,2))
```

And my function is like this:

```
reweight <- function(data, conds){
   require(dplyr)
   require(lazyeval)
   data %>% 
   filter_(lazy(conds)) %>%
   group_by(num_pimp) %>% 
   mutate_(lazy(new_num) = lazy(num_pimp) - lazy(sum(freq[lazy(!conds)]))) %>%   
   mutate(new_weight=freq*(1/new_num)) %>%
   ungroup()
 }

 > reweight(newTest_rv, is_op==0)
```

The non-standard evaluation with the conditional statement "is_op==0" seems to work in other places but not in the subset within a group "lazy(sum(freq[lazy(!conds)]))". Is there any way I can circumvent this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using `mutate` instead of `mutate_`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You subset so only `conds` is true. There will no longer be rows where `!conds` is true so you will never subtract anything from `num_pimp`. What is your desired output here?

Comment: @Benjamin Yes I did. Didn't work :(

Comment: @MrFlick Oh, I mixed up the lines as I was playing with this. The filter should've gone after two mutate statements. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MrFlick So what I'm trying to do is to subtract the sum of `freq` variable in the rows with `is_op != 0` (the condition may differ) within each group **from** `num_pimp` in every row.

Comment: @Benjamin To be more specific, the `lazy` command works fine with `mutate_`, and `mutate` works fine without `lazy` **except** the within group subset part, which is `sum(freq[lazy(!conds)])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you went a bit overboard with the `lazy`s. The `lazy()` function creates a lazy object which basically delays evaluation of an expression. You can't just compose standard expressions and lazy expression. Generally you combine them via lazyeval's `interp()` function. I think what you want is

```
mutate_(new_num = interp(~num_pimp - sum(freq[!(x)]), x=lazy(conds)))
```

Here we use `interp()` to take a standard expression (in this case one that uses the formula syntax) and insert the lazy expression as a subsetting vector.

Comment: This works great and your explanation about `lazy()` and `interp()` clarifies things a lot. Thank you so much!